# How do I make a use effect run before another while using an API in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios

The purpose of this project is to dynamically get the coordinates and bounds from a map API and use its values to get the data of places attached to that area

The situation I have is that on my app.js I have two use effects:

- the first is to get the user's location after the window is loaded this makes it possible for the map API to work.
- the second is to get the data from a different API based on the bounds
  gotten from the map.

  const App =() => {
  const [places, setPlaces]= useState([]);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({lat: 0, lng: 0});
  const [bounds, setBounds]= useState(null);

  ```
       useEffect(()=>{
           let mounted = true;
           window.addEventListener('load', (event) => { 
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({ coords: {latitude, longitude} }) => {
               if (mounted){
               setCoordinates({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude });
               }
           },(err)=> {
               console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
             },{maximumAge:60000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy:true});
             console.log('page is fully loaded');
           });
           return ()=>{
               mounted = false;
           }
       }, []);

       useEffect(() => {

           console.log(coordinates, bounds); 
           let isApiSuscribed= true;
           getPlacesData(bounds.sw, bounds.ne)//I am trying to get the API data using this
            .then((data) => {

                if (isApiSuscribed){
                console.log(data);

                setPlaces(data);
                }
            });
            return ()=>{
                isApiSuscribed=false;
            }
       }, [coordinates,bounds]);

       return(
           <>
               <CssBaseline />
               <Header />
               <Grid container spacing={3} style={{width:'100%'}}>
                   <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                       <List places={places}/>
                   </Grid>
                   <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
                       <Map
                           setCoordinates={setCoordinates}
                           setBounds = {setBounds}
                           coordinates ={coordinates}
                       />
                   </Grid>
               </Grid>
           </>
       )
   }
   export default App;
  ```

The Challenge is that if I do not call the `bounds.sw, bounds.ne` parameters in the `getPlacesData()` function my Locally hosted page would run showing the appropriate Map and other components but the data that I need to fetch from the other API would not work.

And when I then call the `bounds.sw, bounds.ne` parameters in the `getPlacesData()` function  then nothing is rendered on the screen and I get the following error codes:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKbz6.png)

this is the code for the API that is to return the data back

```
import axios from 'axios';

const URL ='https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-in-boundary';



export const getPlacesData = async (sw, ne) => {
  try {
    const { data: { data } } = await axios.get(URL, {
      params: {
        bl_latitude: sw.lat,
        bl_longitude: sw.lng,
        tr_longitude: ne.lng,
        tr_latitude: ne.lat,
      },
      headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_TRAVEL_API_KEY,
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com',
      },
    });

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Please what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you could chain these operations instead of two disconnected `useEffect`s. Try calling the `getPlacesData` function where you're now changing the state using `setCoordinates`, inside the first `useEffect`.

I would also recommend extracting this out into a custom hook to make the code cleaner.

As a side note, you might not actually need `window.addEventListener` since this component will already have mounted when the first useEffect is triggered.

Comment: it did not work still